# rmarkdown website: set automatic width

Tags: html, width, r-markdown

I was previously using [flexdashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) to generate website and it has a nice feature that creates pages that using 100% of the page width and it adapts to any screen size.

Now I am switching to [rmarkdown websites](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-13.html), and it seems that the page and chunck width can only be set as a number of pixel?

Here is my question: is there a way in rmarkdown websites to use the full width screen? (like 100%)

Thank you

Comment: `<style>.main-container { max-width: 100%;}</style>` works for me.

Comment: where to put this line?